# How to make callback function called by several subscriber?

Tags: ros, callback, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to make multi-subscriber that calls same function with different argument.

For example,

```
std::vector<ros::Subscriber> sub;
std::vector<sensor_msgs::JointState> position;

position.resize(2);
sub.resize(2);

for(int i=0; i < sub.size(); i++)
{
   char sub_name[20];
   sprintf(sub_name, "sub_%d", i);
   sub[i] = node.subscribe(sub_name, 1, &Myclass::callback, this);
}

Myclass::callback(const sensor_msgs::JointStateConstPtr &msg)
{
   this->position[i] = *msg;
}
```

So my questions are:

1. How to sent array index i from main function to Myclass::callback?
2. Can several subscriber call same callback function like that?

Thank you for your answer. This is additional question.

I modified source code as follows:

```
position.resize(2);
sub.resize(2);

for(int i=0; i < sub.size(); i++)
{
   char sub_name[20];
   sprintf(sub_name, "sub_%d", i);
   sub[i] = node.subscribe(sub_name, 1, boost::bind(&Myclass::callback, this, _1, i));
}

Myclass::callback(const sensor_msgs::JointStateConstPtr &msg, int i)
{
   this->position[i] = *msg;
}
```

And this is error messages I got.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(char [20], int, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Myclass, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::JointState_<std::allocator<void> > >&, int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Myclass*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >)’
```

and candidates are:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:379:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:390:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M)const, T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:438:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const MReq>&), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:448:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const MReq>&)const, T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:498:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:509:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M)const, const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:559:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const MReq>&), const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:570:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const MReq>&)const, const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:618:14: note: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (*)(M), const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:663:14: note: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&), const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:706:14: note: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)>&, const VoidConstPtr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:752:14: note: template<class M, class C> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(C)>&, const VoidConstPtr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
```

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63991/how-to-make-callback-function-called-by-several-subscriber?/) by [zieben](https://answers.ros.org/users/4652/zieben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use boost::bind to create a "virtual" callback function based on your "real" one. I haven't got the syntax for callbacks to objects in my head right now, but

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++)
     sub[i] = node.subscribe(sub_name, 1, boost::bind(callback, _1, i));
```

would create 10 subscribers that are each tied to the function callback(msg_type msg, int i).

Edit: Using a member-function of an actual object is done the same way as you'd do it without boost::bind.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++)
     sub[i] = node.subscribe(sub_name, 1, boost::bind(&MyClass::callback, this, _1, i));
```

---

Edit 2: With respect to the new question, the first thing I'd try is templating the subscriber to the correct datatype:

```
[...]
sub[i] = node.subscribe<sensor_msgs::JointState>(sub_name, 1, boost::bind(&Myclass::callback, this, _1, i));
[...}
```

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 21

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-11-01**:
The ros2 create_subscription equivalent #q289207